# How does Kon-Boot for Mac actually work?

Tags: windows, macos, passwords, login

Kon-Boot on Windows uses "net user username password" to attempt to create a login with no password.

What commands on MacOS is Kon-Boot using to achieve login with no password (particularly on newer versions such as High Sierra or Mojave)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong about Kon-Boot using "net user".

According to the [documentation](https://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/):

> Our software works by virtually modifying the EFI bios and then modifying parts of the OSX kernel. Such changes are only made in virtual memory and they disappear after computer reboot.

This same method works for Windows. Kon-Boot have found a hook that allows their
software to be loaded before Windows/Mac, then they patch the kernel in memory
once it is loaded, so it either accepts any password,
or they can create a new admin account. They do this for both the Windows
and Mac kernels.

You may call Kon-Boot a Master Boot Record infection or UEFI infection.
It basically infects the startup code when Windows/Mac boots, using methods
similar to those of a virus, only that this one is benign,
does not cause any harm to the computer or leave any trace of it being used.